# How to make a controller to get a URL with HashMap?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller

I need to make a controller in Spring Boot 2.0 to get correctly an URL like this:

https://localhost:8443/my_generate_signature?data%5Btimestamp%5D=1570074358&data%5Bsource%5D=uw

This URL is being called by an AJAX requisition:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var generateSignature = 
function(callback, params_to_sign){
$.ajax({
url     : "/my_generate_signature",
type    : "GET",
dataType: "text",
data    : { data: params_to_sign},
complete: function() {console.log("complete")},
success : function(signature, textStatus, xhr) { callback(signature); },
error   : function(xhr, status, error) { console.log(xhr, status, error); }
});
}
</script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  $('#upload_widget_opener').cloudinary_upload_widget({ 
    cloudName: cloudName, apiKey: api_key,
    cropping: true, uploadSignature: generateSignature}, (error, result) => { });
</script>
```

For reference, I'm trying to implement this:

https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget#create_upload_widget_methods

I've tried a controller like this but I get HttpStatus 400:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/my_generate_signature")
@ResponseBody
public String generateSignature(@RequestParam(value="params_to_sign", required=true) Map<String, Object> paramsToSign) {

return 'test';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save all request parameters into a `Map`, you don't need to identify the `value` for `@RequestParam`. Just modify your method `generateSignature` as follows:

```
public String generateSignature(@RequestParam Map<String, Object> paramsToSign) {
    return 'test';
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can also use a post  request and use request body.
@PostMapping
@ResponseBody
public String generateSignature(@RequestBody Map> paramsToSign) {
    return "....";
}

In case of get request, you can go with @GetMapping and @RequestParam annotation.